# Why is it saying column does not exist for android sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I amp working on an app and I created a database but when I input the data, logcat gives an error saying "column passwords does not exist". Why is this?

Here is my code for the database(part of it):

```
public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_NUMBER = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Snipeshot";

    private static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";

    private static final String KEY_USERNAME ="username ";
    private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password ";

    public DBHandler(Context ctx){
        super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_NUMBER);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_NAME + "(" + KEY_USERNAME + "TEXT, " + KEY_PASSWORD
                + "TEXT" + ");";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
    }
```

and here is the code that inputs data into the database:private class register extends

```
AsyncTask<Object,Void,Boolean>{
        String f,l,d,em,un,pw,cpw;
        boolean success = true;
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            f = fn.getText().toString();
            l = ln.getText().toString();
            d = dob.getText().toString();
            em = e.getText().toString();
            un = u.getText().toString();
            pw = p.getText().toString();
            cpw = cp.getText().toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(f == null || f.equalsIgnoreCase("")  ){
                success = false;
                return false;
            }

            else if(l == null || l.equalsIgnoreCase("") ){
                success = false;
                return false;
            }

            else if(d == null || d.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            {
                success = false;
                return false;
            }

            else if(em == null || em.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                success = false;
                return false;
            }

            else if(un == null || un.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                success = false;
                return false;
            }

            else if(pw == null || pw.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                success = false;
                return false;
            }

            else if(!(cpw.equals(pw))){
                success = false;
                return false;
            }

            if(success){
                db.addUSer(new User(un,pw));
            }

            return true;
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean results){
            results = true;
            ctx.startActivity(new Intent(ctx,SignIn.class));




        }
```

Here is the addUSer code:

```
public void addUSer(User user) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_USERNAME, user.getuserName()); // 
        values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, user.getPassword()); // 

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }
```

Comment: perhaps because your password column is named "password", not "passwords"?

Comment: Agree with @panini, better check `db.addUSer`.

Comment: Does it matter than there is a space after column name? KEY_USERNAME ="username ";

Comment: now it says there is no column named username, but i clearly specified a "username"

Answer (score 1):

From the code above, these are the errors you need to rectify:

1--> Your String variables contains trailing space,

> ```
> private static final String KEY_USERNAME ="username ";
> private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password ";
> ```

Correct it to:

```
private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
```

2--> You should have a `id` column with which you can identify each record uniquely. Also, you wrote `DATABASE_NAME` instead of `TABLE_USERS`, and some corrections regarding spacing in the query string.

> String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_NAME + "(" +
>   KEY_USERNAME + "TEXT, " + KEY_PASSWORD + "TEXT" + ");";

Correct it to:

create a class variable as,

```
private static final String KEY_USERID = "uid";
```

And,

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERS + "(" + KEY_USERID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + KEY_USERNAME + " TEXT, " + KEY_PASSWORD
            + " TEXT" + ");";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_USER_TABLE);
}
```

Dont know if this would be helpful, but incase it does, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There is missing space:

you have to write "  TEXT,  "+

instead of

"TEXT,"+

Comment: There is a space after user and password though. should i still put it?

Comment: I don't know is it a correct way to write spaces in to the variables, I always write them in to the query before and after "text". But if this is the problem, you can see it in the logcat (in the transleated query are the two word wrote in together. If yes that is the problem) output.  Another reason can be, the password was added, after the apk was installed, and the db version wasn't increased. If this is the problem you have to uninstall the app, and install it again, or increase db number.

Answer (score 0):

You do know that your are calling `database name` instead of `table name`

```
private static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";

private static final String KEY_USERNAME ="username ";
private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password ";

public DBHandler(Context ctx){
    super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_NUMBER);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


 //SHouldn't here TABLE NAME COME
    String CREATE_USER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERS + "(" + KEY_USERNAME + "TEXT, " + KEY_PASSWORD
            + "TEXT" + ");";
```